# Google Play shows 7inch tablet scheenshots on smartphones which leads to duplication

Tags: android, google-play, duplicates, app-store

I have lately found out, that there is **duplication in screenshots** on Android smartphones and desktop version of app pages, e.g.

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.global.foodpanda.android&hl=en;
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clickbus.mobile&hl=en.

It seems, **Google Play shows only 7 inch tablet screenhots in addition to smartphones ones**.

*Has anyone had the same problem? How to get rid of such duplication without deleting the screenshots?*

Thank you